# Issues related to poi.ooxml initialize for SoapUI 5.5.0 free version

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am facing issue "Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.poi type loader" error message I am using soapUI 5.5.0 and Poi version:poi-bin-4.0.1-20181203.

Please help I want to read xlsx file data.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple dependencies for `.xslx` first `org.apache.poi » poi` but also `org.apache.poi » poi-ooxml` and `org.apache.poi » poi-ooxml-schemas` since `.xlsx` is an xml-format. That's why the `x` at the end.

see [Maven Repo of POI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi)